# Generate Docx files using html and css with DocumentFormat.OpenXml in ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, openxml, docx

Is it possible to generate Docx files from HTML and CSS using DocumentFormat.OpenXml ?

I want to create an Web API application using ASP.Net Core 2.2 that generates Docx files, and another applications that need to generate Docx, call my Docx generator application.

In other word I want to create an Docx generator that another applications can get help from that(other applications that wants to get help from my Docx generator, can be implemented by any programming language like JavaScript).

Only way that I find to communicate between my applications, is use HTML and CSS strings to generate Docx files from their.

off course, if is possible another better way to do this job, please explains that for me.

currently I'm using DocumentFormat.OpenXml to generate Docx files.

```
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
            {
                wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                // siga a ordem
                Document doc = new Document();
                Body body = new Body();


                // 1 paragrafo
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

                ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
                ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Normal" };
                Justification justification1 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Center };
                ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

                paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
                paragraphProperties1.Append(justification1);
                paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties1);

                Run run = new Run();
                RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();

                Text text = new Text() { Text = "The OpenXML SDK rocks!" };

                // siga a ordem 
                run.Append(runProperties1);
                run.Append(text);
                para.Append(paragraphProperties1);
                para.Append(run);

                // 2 paragrafo
                Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph();

                ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();
                ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId2 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Normal" };
                Justification justification2 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Start };
                ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties2 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

                paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphStyleId2);
                paragraphProperties2.Append(justification2);
                paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties2);

                Run run2 = new Run();
                RunProperties runProperties3 = new RunProperties();
                Text text2 = new Text();
                text2.Text = "Teste aqui";

                run2.AppendChild(new Break());
                run2.AppendChild(new Text("Hello"));
                run2.AppendChild(new Break());
                run2.AppendChild(new Text("world"));

                para2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
                para2.Append(run2);

                // todos os 2 paragrafos no main body
                body.Append(para);
                body.Append(para2);

                doc.Append(body);

                wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document = doc;

                wordDoc.Close();
            }
            return File(mem.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "ABC.docx");
        }
```

Comment: Also I want to generate Docx from html pages ...